# Reverting a specific old commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Hi I have a repository on Bitbucket. I am working with a partner on a project and he pushed some updates few commits ago, working on a file, I realized that he did wrong code. I want to revert that commit, particularly that file only so I can get back code of that file only. cartitems.blade.php

Is this possible?

Attached is the image of SourceTree tool. Uncommited changes are my new changes. I want to keep these and recover that specific file only.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use `git revert` to reverse the effects for a specific commit and create a new commit with the changes reverted.

In this instance

```
git revert 797832c
```

will automatically create a commit with the changes reversed.

Answer (score 5):

To revert **only** the `cartitems.blade.php` file (not the whole commit) you can checkout the version of the file before the "bad" commit:

```
git checkout 41123f6 -- resources/views/cart/cartitems.blade.php
```

Now make sure no other files are staged for commit and commit the file:

```
git add resources/views/cart/cartitems.blade.php
git commit -m "Revert cartitems.blade.php"
```

This way you won't have to rewrite history. I'm not sure if you could do this with the SourceTree GUI, however. You can use the "Terminal" button in the top right corner of SourceTree to open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Like get rid of the last commit "for good" so that it's like it didn't happen?

Suppose the change is already on your master branch:

`git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin master`

That should be enough.

Comment: Maybe force push?

Comment: ```git push -f origin master```, by the way.... git will complain if you do it without -f because origin/master is already past the point you are trying to place the branch on now.

Comment: I am using SourceTree btw, not git terminal directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you already pushed it to your respository and you're working in a large team, be careful, since your mates might get some frustrating merge-conflicts by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a new branch with a specific commit and send a PR to the branch that you need since It has old changes in the old branch as well new revert changes in your new branch.

```
git checkout -b fix/revert-change 7978732
```

Then push the new branch to the remote with `git push`